# Automatic letter connection for plasma cut parts with nested holes

Tags: cad, autocad, cnc, cutting

Something I'm consistently running into as an issue is connecting letters so they don't fall out or leave a missing unconnected hole in a letter that is cut out of metal. Is there a way to automatically do this? I can't find anything on GitHub, but I thought to ask here to see what this community could recommend. Example:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The capability you seek is a function of the software used to create the work on your cutter. Depending on the features of this unspecified software, it may not be possible and would then require that you use another creation/vector editor program to accomplish the desired results.

As an example, laser cutting software may provide such features, as there is a commonality between plasma cutting and laser cutting. One such feature is called a bridge or tab. Additionally, using a stencil typeface will provide this type of result, but may not meet your approval from an appearance standpoint. Searching for "stencil typeface" or "free stencil typeface" will result in a variety of returns of value.